# invalid initialization of reference of type std::vector

Tags: c++, pointers, interface, polymorphism

This is the error:

> DummyService.hpp:35: error: invalid covariant return type for 'virtual
>   std::vector < ResourceBean*,
>   std::allocator < ResourceBean*> >& DummyService::list(const std::string&)'

```
class Bean {
public:
    typedef std::string Path;
    virtual ~Bean() {};
    virtual const Path& getPath() = 0;
    virtual const std::string& getName() = 0;
protected:
    Bean();
};

class ResourceBean: public Bean {
public:
    ResourceBean(const Path& path, const std::string& contents) :
            _path(path), _contents(contents) {
    }
    virtual ~ResourceBean() { }
    virtual const Path& getPath();
    virtual void setPath(const Path& path);
    virtual const std::string& getName();
    virtual void setName(const std::string& name);
private:
    Path _path;
    std::string _name;
};
```

The above `Bean` classes are data representations, and they are used by two different layers. One layer uses the `Bean` interface, just to access the getters for the data. The `ResourceBean` is accessed by the data access object (DAO) classes, which take the data from a database (for example), and fill in the `ResourceBean`.

One responsibility of the DAO is to list the resources given a certain path:

```
class Service {
protected:
    /*
     * Service object must not be instantiated (derived classes must be instantiated instead). Service is an interface for the generic Service.
     */
    Service();

public:
    virtual std::vector<Bean*>& list(const Bean::Path& path) = 0;
    virtual ~Service();
};

class DummyService: public Service {
public:
    DummyService();
    ~DummyService();

    virtual std::vector<ResourceBean*>& list(const ResourceBean::Path& path);
};
```

I think the problem is related with the fact that in `std::vector<ResourceBean*>` the compiler does not understand that `Bean` is actually the base class of `ResourceBean`.

Any suggestions? I've read to some similar topics but some of the solutions did not work in my case. Please point out if I have missed something. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Before you go any further, notice that your code is not typesafe (it it were to compile). A `std::vector<ResourceBean*>` is not a valid subtype (in the general LSP sense) of a `std::vector<Bean*>`, because a `std::vector<ResourceBean*>` does not support all the operations that a `std::vector<Bean*>` does (for example, you can put any `Bean*` into a `std::vector<Bean*>`, while you may only put a `ResourceBean*` into a `std::vector<ResourceBean*>`).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm trying to understand why you say that "a std::vector<ResourceBean*> does not support all the operations that a std::vector<Bean*> does". Also, when you say "you can put any Bean* into a std::vector<Bean*>, while you may only put a ResourceBean* into a std::vector<ResourceBean*>", do you mean that you can put any Bean* (including * to derived classes)?

Comment: Yes. For example you **can** put a `FooBean*` into a `std::vector<Bean*>` (where `FooBean` is some subclass of `Bean`), but you **can't** put a `FooBean*` into `std::vector<ResourceBean*>`. If some code uses `Service::list` and expects a reference to `std::vector` that a `FooBean*` can be placed into, then the `std::vector<ResourceBean*>` returned by `DummyService::list` will not be enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::vector<Bean*>` and `std::vector<ResourceBean*>` are two completely distinct types that are not convertible to each other. You simply cannot do that in C++ and should stick with a vector of pointer to the base class instead. Also, because of that, having that function `virtual` is not doing what you think it does — different return types make it a different method signature so instead of overloading a method, you introduce a new virtual method. Also, there is no need to make a constructor protected for an abstract class (`Service`) because you cannot create instance of an abstract class anyway. I'd write it something like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class Bean {
  public:
    typedef std::string Path;

    Bean() {}
    virtual ~Bean() {}

    virtual void say() const
    {
        std::cout << "I am a bean!\n";
    }
};

class ResourceBean : public Bean {
  public:
    ResourceBean() {}
    virtual ~ResourceBean() {}

    virtual void say() const
    {
        std::cout << "I am a resource bean!\n";
    }
};

class Service {
public:
    Service() {}
    virtual ~Service() {}

    virtual std::vector<Bean*>& list(const Bean::Path &path) = 0;
};

class DummyService: public Service {
  public:
    DummyService()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
            beans_.push_back(new ResourceBean());
    }

    virtual ~DummyService() {}

    virtual std::vector<Bean *>& list(const Bean::Path &path)
    {
        return beans_;
    }

  private:
    std::vector<Bean*> beans_;
};

int main()
{
    DummyService s;
    std::vector<Bean *>& l = s.list("some path");
    for (std::vector<Bean *>::iterator it = l.begin(), eit = l.end();
         it != eit; ++it)
    {
        Bean *bean = *it;
        bean->say();
    }
}
```

Comment: Makes sense, but a Bean class cannot be filled in with data (since it contains only getters). Is there any way of returning std::vector<Bean*>& in the list method of DummyService, but converting from ResourceBean to Bean in that method?

Comment: @user1570742: `ResourceBean`, when inherited from `Resource`, is implicitly convertible to `Resource`, its base class. I've edited my answer and added some example for that.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain this. It works perfectly now.